# Things will get easier as time goes by

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does it mean?

> Things will get easier as time goes by.

Is it that your life will be happier/better in future despite of the current situation? Can this phrase be used in business or it's only about personal life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily about business or one's personal life.  It depends on what one is talking about.

It generally means "the situation of the world" or "the things that involve us" will **gradually** improve as time passes.

Example:

> John:  The economy is bad right now.
> Carol:  Don't worry.  Things will get easier as time goes by.

Meaning:  prices will be lower, people will have more jobs, inflation will not skyrocket, the economy will expand, trade will improve, etc.

The general situation will improve and be easier for living.

Comment: You can also think of it this way:  "Things (in general) will get easier as time goes by."